# Streaming MP3 with open source PHP

Tags: php, open-source, audio, streaming, mp3

What are the best PHP solutions for a [blip.fm](http://blip.fm)-like fixed audio player?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use XMoov to do this: http://stream.xmoov.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options, either use a flash based solution, there's plenty of examples [here](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/10-easy-to-implement-flash-based-mp3-players-for-your-website/).

Otherwise if flash is a problem you can try using the new html 5 audio tag, the spec is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp).